# Transfer data between two activities

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send and receive data between two different activities. I have seen some other questions asked on this site but no question has dealt with preserving the state of the first class.

For example if I want to send an integer X to class B from class A then to do some operations on integer X and then send it back to class A, how does one go about doing this?

Is it as simple as the following code?

in Class A

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
 i.putExtra("Value1", 1);
 startActivity(i);
```

and to receive the response from Class B:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int value1 = extras.getint("Value1",0);
```

in Class B

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int value1 = extras.getint("Value1",0);
//Do some operations on value1 such as maybe adding or subtracting
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", 1);
startActivity(i);
```

This does not seem correct as I simply want to switch back to Activity A and receive the data from Activity B once the action is completed (perhaps a button in Activity B commences operations on the received data and then sends it back to Activity A?)

Comment: `startActivityForResult` tada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In First activity :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "1");
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

Receive data like :

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
if(receiveIntent!=null){
   String value1 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("Value1");
}
```

After **some operations** In second activity:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Handle result in `FirstActivity` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, how does the second activity receive the intent? Sorry I am a complete novice at Android development.

Comment: check updated ans.

Comment: Thanks this worked :).

Comment: How does it work without 'startActivityForResult()'  ? you should use 'startActivityForResult()'  instead of 'startActivity()'..

Comment: @AGMTazim updated

Answer (score 3):

**`startActivityForResult()` and  `onActivityResult()` is your solution.**

In your `ActivityA`. Use `startActivityForResult()` -

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
 i.putExtra("Value1", 1);
 startActivityForResult(i, requestCodeForOperation);
```

And on your ActivityB, get your data sent from `ActivityA`. Like -

```
int value1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Value1", 0);
```

Do your operation and use `setResult()` for adding you operation result and `finish()`. like-

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

And of course you need to implement  `onActivityResult()` on `ActivityA` to get returned data from `ActivityB`. Like -

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == requestCodeForOperation) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getIntExtra("result", 0);
        }
    }
}
```