# onActivityResult ResultCode always 0

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I always get `ResultCode = 0` with code below. 

This is my code for proccess `setResult`

```
  @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Debug.i("Response Status Complete " + response.code());
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                Debug.i("Response Status Complete " + response);

                mSectionTopic.isComplete = 1;
                mSectionTopic.status = "completed";

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(Util.getIntentName("sectionTopic"), mSectionTopic);
                intent.putExtra(Util.getIntentName("challengeId"), "AIzaSyBkSGK9geQ4QbnvXcQQ_m2JScd7r89xnJs");
                intent.putExtra(Util.getIntentName("position"), mPosition);

                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();

            } else {
                showError(getString(R.string.text_post_question_failed));
            }
```

But if code `onBackPressed();` resultcode works correctly.

What's problem with my code?

--

This is my **`onActivityResult()`**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) return;
        int position = data.getIntExtra(Util.getIntentName("position"), 0);
        mAdapter.setComplete(position);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code when you start activity and when you set the result to activity.

Comment: @AGMTazim cek my updated question, sir.

Comment: What do you mean by "But if code onBackPressed(); resultcode works" ?

Comment: @Arnab yeah if i use process `Intent` and `setResult` in `onBackPressed`, i did'nt got `resultCode = 0`

Comment: How you are starting activity? Are using startActivityForResult()?

Comment: @Chandrakanth no, im using `setResult`

Comment: If you starting activity B from activity A, to get result from B to A, you have to start activity B by using startActivityForResult() method from activity A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` properly. Follow the instructions from here -  [Transfer data between two activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731559/transfer-data-between-two-activities/46731858#46731858)